# Pattern to manage HTTP request chains

Tags: http, clojure

I need to make a chain of HTTP requests to an external service. For each request I need to handle both the failure and success cases. Sometimes this can be 3+ requests deep and it can become a bit unruly. What are some ways to manage this?

```
(ns someproject.namespace
  (:require [clj-http.client :as http]))

(defn http-flow []
  (let [resp-1 (http/post some-url-1 {:form-params {:foo "bar"}
                                      :as :json
                                      :throw-exceptions false})
        (if (= (:status resp-1) "200")
          (let [resp-2 (http/post some-url-2 {:form-params {:bar "baz"}
                                              :as :json
                                              :throw-exceptions false})]
            (if (= (:status resp-2) "200")
              {:success true}
              {:success false}))
          {:success false})]))
```

Answer (score 3):

So I see that you want to return one value if **all** of the urls are successful and return another if **one of them** is unsuccessful. This is exactly what `and` does.

I have defined a helper function for the making of the post request

```
(defn http-request-succeeded [url params]
  (let [request (http/post url params)]
    (= "200" (:status request))))
```

And you could either just call each one in an `and` function like below:

```
(if (and (http-request-succeeded some-url-1 params-1)
         (http-request-succeeded some-url-2 params-2))
  {:success true}
  {:success false})
```

Or use a macro for greater reuse/clarity:

```
(defmacro do-all-> [& requests]
  `(if (every? identity ~requests)
     {:success true}
     {:success false}))

(do-all-> (http-request-succeeded some-url-1 params-1)
          (http-request-succeeded some-url-2 params-2))
```

Comment: It's more complicated if it needs to be really used. `:message` should be included to indicate the error message and often the result of the first request needs to be used in the second request. It's likely a macro is what I want since I need short circuit capability.